# Rank within Groups in Pig 11

Tags: jython, apache-pig

Pig question,

I have my data setup the following way.

```
Function    Group   Home    Name
Rent    MX  1   John
Rent    MX  1   Jake
Rent    MX  1   Pat
Rent    DG  2   Jason
Rent    DG  6   Patrick
Rent    DG  6   Smith
Rent    DG  6   Joe
```

What I want to do is Group by function,group and home and then rank within that group.

```
Function    Group   Home    Name    Rank
Rent    MX  1   John    1
Rent    MX  1   Jake    2
Rent    MX  1   Pat 3
Rent    DG  6   Patrick 1
Rent    DG  6   Smith   2
Rent    DG  6   Joe 3
```

The RANK function in Pig does not allow me to RANK within group.Any suggestions? Jython UDF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this worked

```
def num_bag(input):
output = []
for rank, item in num(input):
    output.append(tuple([rank] + list(item)))
return output
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Enumerate UDF in DataFu, it does this for you. http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/bags/Enumerate.html

Answer (score 0):

I will give some pointers to this.

In Cascading API ,I used [buffer](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/1.2/userguide/html/ch05s05.html) which allows us to iterate the group values.

I read that [cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) also has an api for `Jython` developers ,you may explore that.